# How to alert php warning messages?

Tags: php, jquery, error-handling

```
function validatexml() {
    var xmlfile = "<?php echo $_SESSION['downxml'];?>";
    $.post('xmlvalidate.php', { xmlfile : xmlfile }, function (data) {
        if ($.trim(data) == 'Y') {
            alert('Xml file is valid against NLM 2.3 DTD');
        } else {
            alert('Xml file is not valid against NLM 2.3 DTD<br>Additional Note: ' + data);
        }
    });
}
```

`xmlvalidate.php` will return a warning message If I execute it through the browser. From the script (which is mentioned above) I will get an output in the variable `data`.

I need to alert warning messages also which is returned by `xmlvalidate.php`. How to do it?

I have gone through the function `error_get_last()` But it returns only the last warning message. I need to get all the warning messages. How can I do it?

Comment: That depends on how you handle errors. You could set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and display errors - but not really suitable for a production environment. How are you handling your errors in your PHP script & what type of errors do you need to display (ie: `E_NOTICE`, `E_FATAL`, `E_WARNING`, ...)`?

Comment: I am not 100% sure about what you exactly want but according to me you have to create an array and put your all "alert warning messages which is returned by xmlvalidate.php" into this array and then show it in any manner as you want.

Comment: `xmlvalidate.php` will return only a warning message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On PHP side you can use [`libxml_get_errors()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php):

```php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

/* do validation stuff here */

$errors = libxml_get_errors();
```

[Dealing with XML errors](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php) in PHP explains that:

> The [libXMLError](http://php.net/manual/en/class.libxmlerror.php) object, returned by libxml_get_errors(), contains
>   several properties including the message, line and column (position)
>   of the error.

There is also an example with loading invalid XML:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$sxe = simplexml_load_string("<?xml version='1.0'><broken><xml></broken>");
if ($sxe === false) {
    echo "Failed loading XML\n";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "\t", $error->message;
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Failed loading XML
    Blank needed here
    parsing XML declaration: '?>' expected
    Opening and ending tag mismatch: xml line 1 and broken
    Premature end of data in tag broken line 1
```